# PYTHONPATH prevents import from current directory

Tags: python-3.x, import, module, path

I a Python project, I import code from a module that resides in the 'current' directory, in `./DIR/module.py`:

```
import DIR.module
```

This worked perfectly until I had the idea to place common modules in a central location. To do this, I defined `PYTHONPATH` and moved these modules there.

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/repository
```

I now am able to import from this location, but the import from the 'current' directory no longer works. It therefore seems that PYTHONPATH prevents this type of 'local' import.

How can I add this extra directory without breaking import relative from where the python code file resides? In other words, I'd like to still be able to write `import DIR.module` alongside with imports from the new repository.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've got precisely the opposite problem. I want to set PYTHONPATH and not import from local files, but the local files seem to get precedence.

Answer (score 0):

You could have overwritten the default pythonpath.

You could try the solution from here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/250929/pythonpath-environment-variable

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/dev/python-files
```

Comment: PYTHONPATH is not even defined in my environment, so that appending does not help.